# Complicated Laravel relationship to generate view

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I have Orders which contain any number of items stored in the items table (so a belongsToMany relationship between the two). The items are also categorized under itemtypes. When creating or editing an order I would like to load all items, categorized by itemtype, whether or not that order has any of the items. I was able to pull that up generically using the following:

```
$itemtypes = \App\Itemtype::with('items')
            ->orderBy('id','asc')
            ->get();
```

Then I loop through:

```
@foreach( $itemtypes as $itemtype )
  {{$itemtype->name}}
  @foreach( $itemtype->items as $item )
    {{$item->name}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This gives me something like:

NICU Items
- Baby Blanket
- Beaded Baby Cuddler

Miscellaneous Items
- Fitted Sheet
- Microfiber Towel

However, when I'm accessing a specific order which has records in item_order I want to display the saved quantities (stored in the pivot table). I know one way would be to add records for all items to item_order for every order created but that seems rather inefficient.

Item.php

```
public function orders() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'item_order', 'item_id', 'order_id') -> withPivot('id','quantity','createdby_user_id','weight','cost_billed', 'calc_by_weight', 'track_units');
}
```

Order.php

```
public function items() {
  return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_order', 'order_id', 'item_id') -> withPivot('id','quantity','quantity_received','quantity_delivered','notes', 'createdby_user_id', 'weight', 'cost_billed', 'calc_by_weight', 'track_units');
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm on the trail to a solution. I'm converting the collection to an array, loaded up with all items, modifying the array as needed, then using array_merge to replace the items that have quantities already in item_order.

This all works great - the only issue I'm having now is that when I load the order with it's items, items have an itemtype - a categorization and I'd like to group them by that. I'm not sure how to add a groupby to a relationship. If I figure it all out i'll post the full answer then.

Comment: with that title I thought someone ask about my wife. And no, I neither haven't the answer to solve it.

Comment: I didn't get it.. Why would you have to create records for each pair of `item_order?` Wouldn't you `items()` relationship returns only if your order have any  item?

Comment: Yes it would. But when I display an order I want to display ALL items in the items table, not just those that are associated with the order. For items that are associated with the order (through item_order) it would show the quantity from the pivot.

Comment: your order doesn't belongsToMany but hasMany, you have order that has many items and item that belongs to order and has one item type. if you set it up correctly you should be able to do Orders::all()->with('items')->with('type')->get() and you should get all the relations, if it's not working for you let me know and i'll come up with other solution for you :)